# How to add text between div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I've following HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<p style="text-align: justify;">Some text paragraph</p>
<br/>
<form></form>
</div>
```

I want to add following HTML dynamically to above HTML after `<br/>`. How should I do?

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    response<!-- response is the variable containing the text to be added--->
    </div>
```

Comment: "*Add*" it where? In response to *what*?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Actually I want to create it inside <div class="modal-body"><p></p><br/><!---- Lots of HTML code ---></div>. I want the content to be added after the line <div class="modal-body">

Comment: Of course, but you still need to say where; in the middle, at the beginning, at the end? And is this the HTML string returned in the `response` variable from the previous version of your question?

Comment: @DavidThomas:Just edited my comment for it. It should be after the <p></p><br/>

Answer (score 1):

To insert HTML to a given element, in this case (it appears) `div.modal-body`, from a string of HTML (`var htrmlString = "<div><button>...</button></div>"`, for example), you can use `prependTo()` or `prepend()`:

```
$(htmlString).prependTo('div.modal-body');
```

Or:

```
$('div.modal-body').prepend(htmlString);
```

Similarly, though slightly more complex, you could use:

```
$(htmlString).insertBefore('div.modal-body:first-child');
```

---

The following is the original answer to original version of the question (since edited by OP to correct it).

The easiest solution would be:

```
$('div.alert.alert-danger.alert-dismissible').append(response);
```

Though you could also (if you don't mind losing all bound event-handlers, and recreating your DOM):

```
$('#div.alert.alert-danger.alert-dismissible').html(function (index, html){
    return html + ' ' + response;
});
```

Note that you appear to be confused by CSS selectors:

- `#alert-danger`: selects an element with `id="alert-danger"`, whereas:
- `.alert-danger`: selects elements with a `class` of, or including, `alert-danger`.

The selector I used, above, `div.alert.alert-danger.alert-dismissible` selects `<div>` elements that have *each* of the classes specified (`alert`, `alert-danger` and `alert-dismissible`).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
- [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).
- [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).

Comment: id selector not matching however

Comment: `alert-danger` is a `class`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I posted the question wrongly. Now I've corrected it. I've edited my question. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Yes checked the answer but you are not adding <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button> before the response text.

Comment: *What response text*? Will you please update your question to include *all the information you seem to be missing* to form a coherent question? What HTML do you want to add? Where do you want to add it? In what element, in what position? Where, and what, is 'response text'? Assume we know nothing about your situation (and, frankly, after your edits and updates I think I know *less* now than I did when we started).

Comment: @DavidThomas:I've refined my question content. Now you'd get some better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You must use append method and use class instead of id in selector:

```
$('.alert-danger').append(response);
```